# Why is php/mysql converting this character?

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a database which contains utf8_unicode_ci strings. Some examples are "Zìzhìqū" and "Shěng".

When I run this code:

```
    $result = mysql_query ("SELECT foo FROM bar");

$rows = Array ();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row ($result))
    array_push ($rows, $row [0]);

mysql_free_result ($result);
```

the `$rows` array contains "Zìzhìqū" where expected but "Shěng" has become "Sh?ng". When I write the string to a file, I can see that the rogue question mark is a normal ASCII 0x3f.

WTF?

I am using PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 and mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.24. Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: Have you read this > http://kunststube.net/frontback/ ?

Answer (score 0):

http://cameronyule.com/2008/07/configuring-mysql-to-use-utf-8/

Comment: A link alone does not constitute an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the character encoding for the *connection* between PHP and MySQL to UTF-8? Not doing so will result in `?` being substituted in place of UTF-8 characters.

```
SET NAMES 'utf8'
```

Answer (score 0):

pls keep your database in `DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8` and `COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci`

then

```
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
//mysql connection
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
```